# Overloading rvalue/const lvalue for pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I'm using gcc 4.8.4.

The following code fails with a compiler error from line 22 (indicated):

> invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int*&&’ from expression of type ‘int* const’

Why isn't the call to `square(ptr)` using the lvalue version of `square`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int square(int* &&num) {
    std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
    std::unique_ptr<int> x(num);
    const auto ptr = x.get();
    return square(ptr);  // this is line 22
}

int square(const int* &num) {
    std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl;
    return (*num) * (*num);
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> up(new int);
    *up = 5;
    std::cout << square(up.release()) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is `square(const int* &)` forward-declared before `square(int*&&)`? If not, then `square(int*&&)` doesn't know that `square(const int* &)` exists and thus tries to call itself recursively instead, which it can't because a `const int*` can't be assigned to a `int*&&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have order problem:

```
return square(ptr);
```

only see `int square(int* &&num)` declaration and is invalid

And `int square(const int* &num)` sould be `int square(int*const &num)`.

[Fixed version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/233caf1bac03a95b).

Comment: `const int*` and `int* const` are two different things.  The first is a non-const pointer to a const `int`, the second is a const pointer to a non-const `int`.

Answer (score 1):

At line 22, the only definition of `square()` in scope is the one that takes an rvalue reference - `int square(int* &&)`.  `ptr` is an lvalue, so the error message explains the difference in type.

If you swap the order of the function definitions so that `int square(const int* &)` is also in scope, you'll still get the same error.  That is because you have a pointer to a mutable `int`, so the lvalue function is still not a candidate.

You can change that to accept a const reference to a pointer to int:

```
int square(int *const& num) {
    std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl;
    return (*num) * (*num);
}
```

And now the program compiles and runs.

Obviously, this can be simplified to accept `num` by value, but I'm guessing you want to make this work with something more heavyweight than `int`.

## Rewritten example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int square(int *const& num) {
    std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl;
    return *num * *num;
}

int square(int*&& num) {
    std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
    std::unique_ptr<int> x(num);
    const auto ptr = x.get();
    return square(ptr);
}

int main() {
    auto up = std::make_unique<int>(5);
    std::cout << square(up.release()) << std::endl;
}
```

As a side note, I try to avoid `unique_ptr::release()` - it can be useful when interfacing with pre-C++11 code that takes ownership of naked pointers, but it's hard to reason about it without following the code in detail. Modern code should prefer to pass the smart pointer:

```
int square(std::unique_ptr<int>&& x) {
    std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
    const auto ptr = x.get();
    return square(ptr);
}

int main() {
    auto up = std::make_unique<int>(5);
    std::cout << square(std::move(up)) << std::endl;
}
```

Here, it's much clearer that `square()` will take ownership of its argument.